# Put userdata on lua stack in a thread-safe manner

Tags: c, lua

I have a C function, that calls a lua function, that in turn initiate a long chain of async callbacks that hop between C and lua. And I want all of the C functions involved to be able to access some specific userdata, that I created in the original C function. But the tricky part is: all of this should be thread-safe, and also I can't change API, so passing a reference value throughout callbacks is not an option.

So is there a way to somehow put userdata inside lua_State, in a way that only "my" chain of callbacks could access it?

Comment: It is unclear whether `luaL_ref` could be used due to *passing a reference value throughout callbacks is not an option*.

Answer (score 0):

Because Lua has no thread safety guarantees for data races within the same `lua_State` instance, I'll assume your C code ensures that only one piece of code is communicating with the same `lua_State` at any one time.

The usual way to handle this is through the [Lua registry](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.5). It is a special table that is part of the `lua_State`, accessible from any C code. You designate some key in the registry table to be your special value.

Lua code cannot access the Lua registry unless some C code gives them access to it (BTW: don't do this). So as long as you maintain the integrity of this table, you don't have to worry about a Lua script reaching out and breaking it.